# Class 'String' has no instance method 'map'

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am using the flutter carousel code and trying to add images from firebase.
This is my code:

```
class FullscreenSliderDemo extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color(0xFF030164),
      body: StreamBuilder(
        stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('quotes').snapshots(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (!snapshot.hasData) return Text('Loading data... Please Wait');

          final double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
          return Container(
              height: 100.0,
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
              child: new ListView(
                  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                  children: snapshot.data.documents
                      .map<Widget>((DocumentSnapshot document) {
                    return CarouselSlider(
                        options: CarouselOptions(
                          height: height,
                          viewportFraction: 1.0,
                          enlargeCenterPage: false,
                        ),
                        items: (document.data()['img']).map(
                          (item) => Container(
                            child: Center(
                                child: Image.network(
                              item,
                              fit: BoxFit.cover,
                              height: height,
                            )),
                          ),
                        ).toList());
                  }).toList(),));
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I am getting the error `Class 'String' has no instance method 'map'.` and I'm not sure how to resolve this. If anyone could help, I would appreciate it!

Comment: Seems like `document.data()['img']` is not a list, check its type.

Comment: @fartem I am not too sure how I would do that do you have any advice?

Comment: You can do this by debugging your app. Set breakpoint on line with this variable and when code called IDE stops execution and showed data about current state of app execution. It also prints a type if you pointed to this line in an editor.

Comment: @fartem I believe it is a string if that helps.

Comment: `String` class doesn't contains `map` method.

Comment: If there is only a single image, why are you trying to put it in a carousel? Why not just return a single `Center(child: Image.network(...))`?

Comment: @fartem I know but I think when I map through the ```DocumentSnapshot``` it then returns them as individual images instead of in a list and im not sure how to resolve this issue

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I have multiple images in cloud firestore not just one

Comment: Multiply images for each item in Firestore or item can contains one image?

Comment: @fartem Each item contains one image

Comment: You already iterating documents and you should get an image by `document.data()['img']` and pass it to `Image.network` widget.

Comment: @fartem I tried to do ```items: (document.data()['img'])``` but then I get the error ```type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'List<Widget>'```. Is this what you meant by your comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like this:

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color(0xFF030164),
      body: StreamBuilder(
        stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('quotes').snapshots(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (!snapshot.hasData) return Text('Loading data... Please Wait');

          final double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
          return CarouselSlider(
            options: CarouselOptions(
              height: height,
              viewportFraction: 1.0,
              enlargeCenterPage: false,
            ),
            items: snapshot.data.documents
              .map<Widget>((document) {
                return Container(
                  child: Center(
                    child: Image.network(
                      document.data()['img'],
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                      height: height,
                    )
                  ),
                ),
              ).toList()
            )
          )
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

With this you have only one `CarouselSlider` for all documents/images, instead of a separate one for each document.

Comment: Hi thanks for answering but for some reason it's not showing any images but not giving me any errors either :( @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: It was missing a `return` that I just added. I highly recommend setting breakpoints, and stepping through code in a debugger, as that will allow you to spot many more problems on your own.